# Unable to center navbar when using display:table-cell;

Tags: html, css

I was attempting to vertical align some text in a li element, but the only way I could do it was applying `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:middle;` to the li element.

When I do this, it causes the entire navbar to lose its horizontal center. I have done very much Googling and have not found a solution.

HTML:

```
<div class="h_logo"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/800x200/000/fff.jpg"></div>
<div class="h_nav">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Hosting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Consulting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/** All code is written in chronological form as with the HTML code.
* h. = header.element
* b. = body.element
* sl./sr. = sidebarleft or right.element
**/
.h_logo{
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:800px;
height:200px;
margin:auto;
position:static;
}
.h_nav{
position:inherit;
margin-top:10px;
}
.h_nav li{
list-style-type:none;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
width:150px;
height:35px;
background-color:black;
}
.h_nav a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:20px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wYPM2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this to your CSS:

```
nav ul {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```